# Sending two data arrays to view from controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send two data arrays from my controller to view how can I do it ?
Following is my controller code

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
 public function box() {
    $url = $this->pageURL();
    $id_from_url = explode('/', $url);
    $id = $id_from_url[6];
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
    $row = $query->row();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    if ($rowcount <= 0) {
        echo 'ID not found';
    } else {
        $box_id = $row->idmc_boxes;
        $customer_id = $row->customers_idcustomers;
        $language_id = $row->languages_idlanguages;
        $template_id = $this->getTemplateID($box_id);
        $template_data = $this->getTemplateData($template_id);
        $variables_data = $this->getVariables($customer_id, $language_id);
        $title = $variables_data[0]['value'];
        $this->load->view('template', $template_data);
    }
  }
}
```

In my template view when I echo $title it says it is undefined 
how can I send the whole $variables_data array with $template_data array

Thanks :)

Comment: You should check out the **User Guide** it is very thorough: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using each array ,all do set to one

Like that,giving important sections only

```
...................
$data['template_data'] =  $this->getTemplateData($template_id);

$data['variables_data'] =  $this->getVariables($customer_id, $language_id);

$data['title'] =  $variables_data[0]['value'];

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

you can take $template_data and  $variables_data in view files

Comment: template_data is normal array and variables_data is a multi dimensional array how to get specific array items in view then ?

Comment: You can iterate through any level of array in view file . It will works the same fashion in normal php page

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and quick response :)

Comment: don't forget to add, before doing anything: $data = array();

Answer (score 0):

Generally you pass in data as:

```
$data['template_data'] =  $template_data;
$data['title'] =  $$title; 
....
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```